# What is the purpose of event in C++?

Tags: c++-cx

I read the [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b612y2s.aspx) for `event` but I'm still having issues understanding what it allows you to do. I understand that it triggers upon a certain event occurring and will notify the `event handlers`, but would like to see some examples of this.

Thanks!

Comment: It's too broad, asking for a rationale, so voting to close. But in general, a simple *callback* is when you pass a function F to some other function, that will call it, perhaps repeatedly, and then return. An *event* is when you store a function F in some place known to some software thingy S, so that when you use the functionality of S it will sometimes, at appropriate moments, call F. Perhaps to notify you that a window has been resized, whatever.

Comment: Note that standard C++ doesn't have event handling. Different vendors define their own custom language extensions for event handling. With modern C++ none of that is really needed.

Comment: It is a high-level abstraction for a member function pointer.  The user presses a button in your UI and your Click event handler function runs.  Practically any GUI class library has something like this, Qt abstracted it with "signals and slots" for example.  MFC did it with macros, a basic reason why almost nobody uses it anymore.  The best way to see it used is by reviewing the [C++ samples for UWP](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples).